# PHP arrays of objects with mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Is there an easy way to make an array of objects in php when you have the objects attributes come from a mySQL query?

My code is below in order to show you what I'm doing.  I'm probably far off because I'm not used to php at all and I can't grasp it for some reason.

```
    public function loadMeals(){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, dishName, ingredients FROM meals");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $dishName, $ingredients);
    $meals = array();
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {

        $this->id = $id;
        $this->dishName = $dishName;
        $this->ingredients = $ingredients;
        $meals[] = $this;
    } 
    return $meals;
}
```

Keep in mind that this is all in a class Meals.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Can you post the `__construct()` from the `Meal` class?

Comment: Ok thanks - I wanted to verify that your constructor wasn't taking additional parameters, so Meal can be instantiated easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on how you are using it (creating an array of `Meal` objects, the method should be declared as  a `static` method, called without `$this` context.  The loop may create `Meal` objects via `new self()` and set the appropriate properties before appending onto the array.

If you think about it, this method's purpose is not to act on a single `Meal`, so it makes sense for it to be `static`.

Since it is called without `$this` context, you will need to pass the MySQLi connection as a parameter

```
public static function loadMeals($conn) {
    // Do the query/fetch like you already have
    // except that $conn is a local param, not a class prop.
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, dishName, ingredients FROM meals");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $dishName, $ingredients);
    $meals = array();
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
      // Create a new Meal object
      $meal = new self();
      // And set its properties
      $meal->id = $id;
      $meal->dishName = $dishName;
      $meal->ingredients = $ingredients;

      // Append it to the array
      $meals[] = $meal;
    }
    // Return it
    return $meals;
}
```

To use it, outside the class:

```
// Call the function statically.
// You'll need to pass the database connection to it
$meals = Meal::loadMeals($conn);
```

I'll point out that while it is very good to be in the habit of doing `prepare()/execute()`, you do not actually need it here since you are not passing any input into the query.  You can just call `$conn->query()`, eliminating some complexity from MySQLi's `bind_result()` variable references.

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT id, dishName, ingredients FROM meals");
if ($result) {
  // Fetch and instantiate a Meal object in one go.
  while ($meal = $result->fetch_object('Meal')) {
     $meals[] = $meal;
  }
}
```

Comment: Quick question that you can maybe answer.  I'm used to other languages where you list the attributes at the beginning of the class file and then set them usually in the constructor.  Why is this not usually done in php (at least in our example) and why is self preferred?

Comment: @Requiem In PHP too, you would list properties at the start of the class. But this is a static method. Its job is to list _all_ `Meal`s, not to perform actions on a _single_ meal object, which would require instantiation of that object and calling methods on it directly.  The `self` keyword references the class name of the current class, so it is the same as `$meal = new Meal()` in context of this class.

Comment: There are certainly other ways to architect a "get all the objects" method, using a Factory pattern, for example, instead of calling `new Meal()` directly in this method. That goes much deeper into OO design though.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a short solution to your problem but consider using `mysql_fetch_assoc` when grabbing your elements from the database.

For more reading and example:
[mysql_fetch_assoc documentation from php.net](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc)

Comment: Why are you recommending a function that has a giant deprecation warning in the link you provide?

Answer (score -1):

For PDO:

```
public function loadMeals(){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, dishName, ingredients FROM meals");
    $stmt->execute();
    $meals = array();
    while ($obj = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $meals[] = $obj;
    } 
    return $meals;
}
```

or $meal = $stmt->fetchObject('MyMeal', $ctor_args); See [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) from PHP manual. Also note the first comment about constructors there, to expect the unexpected results that using this may cause.

Comment: This is MySQLi, not PDO, and the OP is intending to return `Meal` objects, not generic `stdClass`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Didn't notice the bind_result. My mistake.